# Nth ordering of matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My limited understanding of Matrix Multiplication is that by convension it's calculated from right to left; similar to how you would pipe functions together since function notation places the symbol to the left of the parenthesis `f(g(h(x))`

Generally speaking, when refering to the `Nth matrix` is it such that the 1rst matrix is the rightmost or leftmost matrix in the multiplication?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix multiplication can be performed both ways: left to right, and right to left. However, matrix multiplication is not conmutative, that is, $AB \neq BA$ (except for some very rare matrices). Since people read from left to right in the West, matrix multiplication is also red that way, so when refering to the $n$th matrix in the multiplication, we are implying the first matrix is the leftmost one.